# Mac OS X How to add text selection context menu

Tags: objective-c, macos

I want add custom text selection context menu of my application.like "Search with google"

[image]

Comment: Do you want to add items to the default menu? Do you want to replace the default menu? In what kind of view is the text? What did you try?

Comment: I want add my custom menu in default context menus on text selection.

Comment: Search with Google is a [Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000101-SW1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add custom menu of application in default context menu we need add Services Properties inside info.plist file.

[image]

Here is the working application
 [Services Demo.](http://member.ipmu.jp/yuji.tachikawa/tmp/services-demo.zip)